# Binding of image trigger in the GroupHeaderTemplate of Xamarin Forms not working

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

This is the group header template. The binding for the image trigger in the view model is not working. I want to change the image according to a tapped event of grouped header. When group header is expanded the image should be ArrowDown and when the group header is collapsed, the image should be up ArrowUp

```xml
                        <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell >
                                    <ContentView >
                                        <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference TheMainPage}, Path=BindingContext.HeaderSelectedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped"/>
                                        </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <StackLayout Padding="15,12,15,12" Orientation="Horizontal"  BackgroundColor="{StaticResource DefaultBackgroundColor}">
                                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                                                <Label Text="{Binding Key.EpisodeModel.EpisodeTitle}"  FontSize="16" TextColor="Black"/>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding Key.EpisodeModel.Department}" />
                                                <Label Text="{Binding Key.EpisodeModel.PeriodOfEpisode}"/>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                            <Label  BackgroundColor="{StaticResource LightAirColor}"  Text="{Binding Key.EpisodeModel.DocumentCount}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="Black"/>

                                            <Image HeightRequest="15">
                                                <Image.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding headerTappedImage}" Value="true">
                                                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="ArrowDown.png"></Setter>
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                    <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding headerTappedImage}" Value="false">
                                                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="ArrowDown.png"></Setter>
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </Image.Triggers>
                                            </Image>

                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </ContentView>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
```

This is my code behind

```cs
 private bool _headerTappedImage;

        public bool headerTappedImage
        {
            get { return _headerTappedImage; }
            set { _headerTappedImage = value; OnPropertyChanged("headerTappedImage");}
        }




        public JournalHistoryViewPage(JournalHistoryPageViewModel journalHistoryPageViewModel) : base(
            journalHistoryPageViewModel)
        {
            headerTappedImage= false;
            InitializeComponent();
            _journalHistoryPageViewModel = journalHistoryPageViewModel;

            DocumentList.RefreshCommand = new Command(RefreshJournalHistoryPage);
        }
```

Logic is not written. but an image should be shown in the header template. but it's not shown. what is the reason for that?

Comment: i would suggest a converter from boolean to image resource. rather than triggers.

Comment: The below answer worked for me. Thanks for the reply @Dilmah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `BindingContext` of `LayoutRoot` below is the same as the `BindingContext` of the `Page`, triggers can be used as suggested in the question:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="LayoutRoot">
  <ListView x:Name="listView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsGroups}"
    ...
    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
              <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference LayoutRoot}, 
                                                      Path=BindingContext.HeaderSelectedCommand}" 
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            ...
            <Image BackgroundColor="White">
              <Image.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" 
                             Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="False">
                  <Setter Property="Source" 
                          Value="{OnPlatform Android=add_black.png, UWP=Assets/add_black.png}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" 
                             Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Source" 
                          Value="{OnPlatform Android=remove_black.png, UWP=Assets/remove_black.png}" />
                </DataTrigger>
              </Image.Triggers>
            </Image>
            ...
```

The `IsVisible` property is part of `Grouping`, example implementation:

```
public class Grouping<K, T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public K Key { get; private set; }

    private bool isVisible;

    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get { return isVisible; }
        set
        {
            isVisible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsVisible)));
        }
    }

    public Grouping(K key, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        Key = key;
        foreach (var item in items)
            this.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

`ItemsGroups` might be defined in the `ViewModel` for `BindingContext` of `LayoutRoot` as follows, definition of `ItemViewModel` not shown:

```
public ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, ItemViewModel>> ItemsGroups { get; set; }
```

A group of items might be added to `ItemsGroups`:

```
var keyForGroupA = "A";
var itemsForGroupA = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
var item1 = new ItemViewModel();
itemsForGroupA.Add(item1);
var item2 = new ItemViewModel();
itemsForGroupA.Add(item2);
...
ItemsGroups.Add(new Grouping<string, ItemViewModel>(keyForGroupA, itemsForGroupA);
```

Example implementation of the `HeaderSelectedCommand`:

```
// in constructor:
HeaderSelectedCommand = new Command(p => HeaderSelectedCommandExecute(p));

// property
public ICommand HeaderSelectedCommand { get; private set; }

// action
void HeaderSelectedCommandExecute(object p)
{
    var grp = (Grouping<string, ItemViewModel>)p;
    grp.IsVisible = !grp.IsVisible;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked after looking for two days.